# How write to xlsm using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am writing this piece of code. My objective is to set a value in a specific cell of this excel file. The code is running quite ok and exits with no error, but the cell A1 remains blank. How can I fix this?

```
import openpyxl
wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsm')
ws = wb.worksheets[1]
ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 999999
wb.save('Test.xlsm')
```

Answer (score 9):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsm',keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value = 9999999
wb.save('Test.xlsm')
```

You need to have '**keep_vba**' enabled since you are trying to modify an .xlsm(Excel Macro Enabled Workbook),I don't know why but this seems to work.

```
wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsm',keep_vba=True)
```

Comment: I really support your answer, but have you any ideas for how can I put in `.cell` a `tuple` contains values instead of insert the index of `row` and `column`, or there's any documetation for this `cell` `def`, please check this link I just posted a question of you could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963471/how-to-modify-cell-in-sheet-in-xlsm-file-using-openpyxl-depending-on-tuple-value

Answer (score 0):

The line `wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsm')` should be
`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Test.xlsm')` based on what you have provided.

Also, are you looking in sheet 2? The line
`wb.worksheets[1]` specifies sheet 2 as sheets are zero-indexed.

Comment: I just canged the line, but it´s still not working. I looked at sheet 2 and the cell is also blank.

Comment: Interesting. I ran with the changed line and it worked. [sheet here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=6832ab0661e0a2dabfefe689d67ea169bbf8c23a5246d65af60a467759a542004f27823ffbca3755c9bb0f2be40d47fdf48020aaa01f3a61220728aad9ae3f70). Maybe there is an issue with the sheet you are loading in.

Comment: Works for me too. @nel_junior000, your code, however, doesn't work as is (if you `import openpyxl` you must do `openpyxl.load_workbook`), which indicates it's not a complete terminal session. You may want to exit the Python shell, run it again and run those exact lines to test.