# How to add a dataframe to an existing Excel sheet with Pandas, on a .xlsm file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to import the values from a Pandas dataframe into an existing Excel sheet. I want to insert the data inside the sheet without deleting what is already there in the other cells (like formulas using those datas etc).

I tried using data.to_excel like:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'path\TestBook.xlsm')    
data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', startrow=1, startcol=11, index = False)    
writer.save()
```

The problem is that this way i overwrite the entire sheet.
Is there a way to only add the dataframe? It would be perfect if I could also keep the format of the destination cells.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you will find the answer here: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas

Comment: My bad, I tried that solution and it didn't work. But I just noticed my file is .xslm, and it gets corrupted when I write on it like that. I'll correct my question.

Comment: Ok, I found that it's sufficient to add keep_vba=True (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470871/how-write-to-xlsm-using-openpyxl ).

Comment: seems like it is not possible to write to `xlsm` files with `pandas`

Comment: It looks like it breaks the macros..

Comment: Maybe try this solution: "You can workaround this with recent versions of XlsxWriter by extracting the VbaProject.bin macro file from a real xlsm file and inserting it into the new file"

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169731/write-pandas-dataframe-to-xlsm-file-excel-with-macros-enabled

Comment: In my head it could work like this: get contents, get macros, add your df to contents and then add the VbaProject.bin macro file to the new file. But then again, I'm by no means an expert.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! They made me understand how Excel actually creates the xlsm file, and I found out that the macros are actually there (because the vba file was mantained), but i can't activate them using the buttons because the link is broken (just like the plots are lost). In the developer tab the macros are actually there and workin.. Now I only have to understand how to keep the graphical inteface alive...

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for it. Xlwings natuarally supports pandas dataframe:
https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#pandas-dataframes

Answer (score 0):

The to_excel function provides a mode parameter to insert (w) of append (a) a data frame into an excel sheet, see below example:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(p_file_name, mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', startrow=2, startcol=2)
```