# VBA macro import txt

Tags: excel, vba, extract, txt

I am trying to extract all the lines from a txt file into excel. Unfortunately, the script that I ended using returns only the first line and I don't see what needs to be modified. Could you please help me with adjusting the code?

```
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.txt")
    rowNum = 1
    Do While myFile <> ""
        fileNum = FreeFile
        Open myPath & myFile For Input As #fileNum
        Do Until EOF(fileNum)
            Line Input #fileNum, textLine
            newSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = textLine
            rowNum = rowNum + 1
        Loop
        Close #fileNum
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
```

Comment: The code itself works. Are you sure the files have <CF><LF> as line ending? If they where created on a Mac or Linux, they have other line endings and `Line Input` will read the file content as one single line

Comment: **Data > Get Data > From Text/CSV** > Navigate to your text file > press Load (or Transform if you want to make changes to data before loading).  No VBA required.

Comment: @FunThomas thank you! This looks like the issue. I checked and at the end of each line there is LF

Answer (score 0):

I had problems trying to do this in the past. I had to do a not so fancy but workable workaround: I renamed the “.txt” file to “.csv” and used the tool Data >> Text to Columns in Excel. Finally, I copied and pasted the data to the final Excel sheet.

If you really need it to be automatic, maybe you can try Python. Using Python, I have been easily reading and writing from/to Excel files. Specially about writing, I recommend you take a look here:
[How write to xlsm using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470871/how-write-to-xlsm-using-openpyxl)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: You don't need to change `.txt` to `.csv`  at all. Copy/pasting is not required either. The key is to [*import* the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77927428/vba-macro-import-txt#comment137382465_77927428).

Answer (score 0):

So there are numerous ways to import the file data with Excel itself and no coding is needed.

However, if you want to use VBA for some reasons (for example because you want to do some modifications to the content), you can use the following function. It will read the content of the complete file in one go and return an array of strings.

```
Function readTextFile(filename As String)
    Dim f As Integer, inputBuffer As String
    
    f = FreeFile
    Open filename For Binary Access Read As #f
    inputBuffer = Space(LOF(f))     ' Size Buffer so that get reads all at once
    Get #f, , inputBuffer
    Close #f
    
    ' Replace all possible line endings with vbLf
    inputBuffer = Replace(inputBuffer, vbCrLf, vbLf)
    inputBuffer = Replace(inputBuffer, vbCr, vbLf)

    ' Create an array of lines
    readTextFile = Split(inputBuffer, vbLf)
End Function
```

You could use this in your code:

```
myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.txt")
rowNum = 1
Do While myFile <> ""
    Dim lines, lineNo As Long
    lines = readTextFile(myPath & myFile)
    For lineNr = 0 To UBound(lines)
        newSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = lines(lineNr)
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Next
Loop
```