# how to open an .xlsm file using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to open an excel file that will execute a macro.
for that i wrote an py code:

```
import openpyxl

from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook

book = load_workbook("openwithpy_V2.xlsm")
sheet = book.active

sheet['A6'].value = 'Run_Code'
book.save('openwithpy_V3.xlsm')
```

The code modified a cell in the excel file that triggers a macro.
I saved the file with another name, but the code makes the file unreadable for excel.

when opening the ...V3.xlsm, excel gives me an error, saying: the file format or extension is not valid.
how can i open the excel file and trigger the macro?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How write to xlsm using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470871/how-write-to-xlsm-using-openpyxl)

Comment: As noted you would want to at least try having 'keep_vba=True' set.

Comment: i love this community! thank you for the link @nbk